# Unable to find the mistake in prime number code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

```
n=5;count=2;i=3;j=2;
while (count <= n):
    for j in range (2,i):
            if(i%j == 0):           
                break
    if(j==i):
        print i
        count = count +1
    i = i+1
```

I am trying to find first n prime numbers but somehow this code doesn't seem to compile.
the program is getting stuck at the **for loop**.
I have tried using writing the code in C using the same logic it seem to work fine but as i need large number support python seem to be an obvious choice and thus wanted to run in python.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Indentation is significant in Python - that should literally be the *first* thing you learn about the language.

Comment: Using meaningful variable names will make your code easier to read and understand

Comment: Style nit: Get rid of the parentheses in the `while` and `if` statements. The parentheses are obvious C-isms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`range(a, b)` goes from `a` to `b-1`.

```
n=5;count=2;i=3;j=2;
while (count <= n):
    for j in range (2,i):
        if(i%j == 0):           
            break
    if(j==i-1):
        print i
        count = count +1
    i = i+1
```

I'm betting you had

```
 int j;
 for(j = 2; j < i; j++) {
 }
```

So that by the end of the loop for a prime number, `j` would be `i`.

Python doesn't overshoot the limit when using `range`.

Comment: Good catch, need to adjust the check, not the range

Comment: +1 Excellent catch. Note, however, that if you use `else:` here, you eliminate the check altogether. This avoids repeating the relationship between `i` and `j`, for [DRYer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) code.

Comment: Instead of changing the if statement i changed the for loop condition and the program ran just fine. thanks for the help

Comment: @CDspace you can check the range and leave the test as is, just like you've suggested in your answer, which is fine btw; the OP actually says here in the comment above that they did exactly that and it worked out OK. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use for the otherwise-obscure syntax of `else:` keyword following a loop. As others have commented, your test for successful completion of the `for` loop is off by one.

Instead, try using `else` to test for successful completion:

```
for j in range (2,i):
        if(i%j == 0):
            break
else:
    print i
    count = count +1
```

Comment: if there's anything distinctly different about Python, it *is* the `for ... else` case. It practically *shouts* at you: "Python"; IOW it's unforgettable once seen. So, "obscure" is not how *I* feel about it. :) (just a side note) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
for j in range (2,i):
```

This checks j=2,3,4....i-1. Thus your code here is never run:

```
if(j==i):
        print i
        count = count +1
```

So count never changes. Thus you get an infinite while loop. Change your check to

```
if(j==i-1):
        print i
        count = count +1
```

Comment: `range(2, i+1)` will make no prime numbers, since `i` always divides `i`.

Comment: @PaulDraper wrong. `range(2, i+1)` will work because `break` will always fire for `j==i` for primes but that doesn't matter because then `if (j==i):` succeeds. This wouldn't work if there was `else:` there, but there isn't `else:` there, there's a test. Moreover, [the OP says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982323/unable-to-find-the-mistake-in-prime-number-code-in-python/19982428#comment29748862_19982428) they "changed the for loop condition and the program ran just fine.".

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, it's `print()`, not `print`. The code compiles when you change this line:

```
        print(i)
```

You also seem to have an infinite loop, but I'll let you debug that.

Comment: HUh...perhaps he's using Python 2. Because he didn't mention that as a problem.

Comment: Yeah, but he did tag it Python 3, and that was the only compile error (which is what he claimed the problem was) in Python 3.